# Ember: count number of keys in object?

Tags: ember.js

I have data that looks roughly like this:

```
"id": "1",
"slug": "WD",
"name": {
    "en": "Working Draft",
    "de": "Arbeitsentwurf",
    "fr": "Version de travail",
    "ja": "草案",
    "ru": "Рабочий черновик"
}
```

And I am passing the `name` object to a component:

```
{{title-name name=model.name lang='en'}}
```

In the component template I would like to output the number of translations

```
<p>Translated {{translationCount}} times.</p>
```

I tried a few different things in my component to come up with this total but none of them work. How would I count the number of objects?

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
   // did not work:    
   translationCount: Ember.computed.alias('Object.keys(name).length'),
   // did not work:
   // translationCount: Ember.computed.alias('name.length'),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Being a little more explicit about it seems to work:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  translationCount: Ember.computed('name', function() {
    return Object.keys('name').length;
  })
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't update if the keys of the object change without changing the object. So if you did `this.get('name')['newKey'] = 'value'`, the count won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [ember-twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com/317b1ae65dc9fdbce475) for an implementation of this.

**Application Template**

```
<h1>Welcome to the {{appName}}</h1>

{{title-name name=data.name lang='en'}}

{{outlet}}
```

**Application Controller**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName:'Stephanie Hobson App',

  data: {
    id: 1,
    slug: 'WD',
    name: {
      en: 'Working Draft',
      de: 'Arbeitsentwurf',
      fr: 'Version de travail',
      ja: '草案',
      ru: 'Рабочий черновик'
    }
  }
});
```

**title-name.js** component

```
import Ember from 'ember';
var { computed, get } = Ember;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  translationCount: computed('name', function() {
    var name = get(this, 'name');
    return Object.keys(name).length;
  })
});
```

**title-name.hbs** component template

```
{{yield}}

{{translationCount}}
```

Comment: @GJK mentioned that my solution won't update if the keys of the object change, will this update if the keys change?